# Sequencing calls to methods: From 1 controller or recursive?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, recursion, software-design

What are the pros and cons of each of the following patterns, demonstrating very common situations, for example initializing process at the beginning of the program:

Recursive calls:

```
void foo1() {
    //do some work
    foo2();
}

void foo2() {
    //do some work
    foo3();
}

void foo3() {
    //do some work
    //end
}
```

or from 1 main controller:

```
void main() {
    foo1();
    foo2();
    foo3();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer without context, but I will anyway :)

The one marked as *recursion* is what you see when a developer does not want his functions to become too long, by moving part of the function to a new function. This is typically a failure to divide the functionality in good units that each fulfill a single responsibility.

The second example (*1 main controller*) is much better. The developer recognized that what needs to be done should be split over three functions, and the top function is a clear delegation to the three steps that need to be performed. Readability is much better here.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would say the term *recursion* is not really appropriate since no method is calling  itself directly or indirectly in your example.

Concerning your question itself, I would say that IMHO both approaches are valid but with different intentions:

- the first means that calling `foo1` for the initialization will imply calling `foo2` while the caller might not be aware of that. You can use this way if you want to ensure that.
- the second means there are (normally) independent steps. It is easier to swap, add or remove one of them. If your methods are distinct and quite independent steps, this is the most accurate.

Note that you can of course mix both.